# Can't get a value out an ASP.NET hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am going through a YouTube video, to learn ASP.NET.  I've gotten it to work for the most part, with a somewhat major caveat: I can't retrieve a value from a hidden field ID.  Because of that, I don't have a value to send to a stored procedure to create or update.

The commented out line is the original statement. When I have that then execute 
`.ExecuteNonQuery`, I get the following error:

> Procedure or function 'ResourceCreateOrUpdate' expects parameter '@ResourceID', which was not supplied

When I try to display hfResourceID, I have nothing when trying to pass 0, for a create, or the ResourceID value, i.e. 1.  That value however, doesn't get there.  I know the stored procedure works because I can execute it in SQL Server Management.

I tried moving hfResourceID to a string, then a integer value, but I seem to be having problems creating the if/else: everything is marked as an error.  When I hover over the lines, I get the following message, which pretty much leave me clueless:

> "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement".

Would I be able to get any pointers on how to clear up my error, please?  Thanks.

**2017-10-13 @ 10:38: code updated**

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfResourceID" runat="server" />

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intResourceID = 0;
        bool boolIDHasValue = true;
        try
        {
            intResourceID = Convert.ToInt32(hfResourceID.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            boolIDHasValue = false;
        }
        if (boolIDHasValue)
        {
            if (sqlconnODRConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlconnODRConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate = new SqlCommand("ResourceCreateOrUpdate", sqlconnODRConnection);
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceID", intResourceID);
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NickName", txtNickName.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USCitizen", txtUSCitizen.Text.Trim());
            sqlcmdCreateOrUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconnODRConnection.Close();
            string strResourceID = hfResourceID.Value;
            Clear();
            if (strResourceID == "")
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Saved Successfully";
            else
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
            FillGridView();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what type of field is it? Maybe try hfResourceID.Text instead of .Value, then parse the string value to an int or whatever type.

Comment: Well, you're not providing a parameter called `"@ResourceID"`.  According to the error, the stored procedure expects that parameter.  It looks like you tried to supply that parameter at some point, but now it's commented out.  Code in comments doesn't execute.

Comment: Additionally, the "embedded statement..." error refers to your if/else blocks.  The *only* thing you do in each block is declare a variable, nothing else.  The compiler doesn't allow that.  There's no purpose to it, the variable would immediately fall out of scope.

Comment: @David Originally, the commented line was not commented and the if/else was not there; I was trying a workaround.  And yes, I understand that the 'embedded' issue came from the if/else; I pretty much added insult to injury.  I'm afraid that I don't understand your 2nd post.  Are you saying that I can't set values under the if and else at the same time?

Comment: @Akerra.  I am using the code that was in the video and it worked for him so I am at a loss why it doesn't work for me.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: You need to create a parameter for the "resourceid" to be passed back to the stored procedure you are making a call against.  Your commented out line should give you the clue... alternatively you can default the parameter in the stored proc to have a default value if nothing is passed in.

Comment: @MonicaCollins: For starters, get rid of everything you're trying to do in the if/else.  You originally had something that wasn't working, then you tried adding a bunch of random things.  Go back to the original problem and we can help solve that.  Don't confuse the problem by adding more problems.

Comment: @David, you are right, I should have started at my original problem.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll make sure to do that in future.  I don't know how to modify my original message above to replace that code with what I had previously.  Going back to that, when I try updating an existing record, hfResourceID.Value shows to contain "1".  When I execute, I get "Procedure or function 'ResourceCreateOrUpdate' expects parameter '@ResourceID', which was not supplied." even though it should have the value of "1".

Comment: @MonicaCollins: Press the "edit" link on the question to modify it.  You're going to need to show us your code in order for anybody to help you with that code.

Comment: @akerra When I try to change Convert.Value to Convert.ToString, the entire parameter errors out.

Comment: @MonicaCollins that's not what I was suggesting. Everywhere you have hfResourceID.Value, change it to hfResourceID.Text.

Comment: Are you sure that hidden field does have value even? instead of checking if its == "" check if its null or not. point a breakpoint and track it carefully.

Comment: Ok, I trying copying into the comment and it looked like crap.  I don't have an edit button for my original entry.  I've looked.  The only ones I have are for the comments.  I'm sure that I'm missing something that is probably right out in the open.

Comment: @akerra I tried that and got an error on the entire parameter.

Comment: @ecKO When I debug and follow the execution, under Autos, I see "1" for hfResourceID.Value when working with record #1.  When I tried to add, I see "".

Comment: Is there a way to add screen shots to my post?

Comment: I found the edit button.  I figured it was in plain sight lol.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code you copied from that video. But here a snippet as to how it should be done. I've added 3 ways to convert from the HiddenField value to an actual `int`. Which one you use can depend on how you want to handle errors, 0 values etc. Not included in the snippet, but I like to check for IsNullOrEmpty while using `Trim()`, that gets rid of spaces that might make the value non-convertible `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfResourceID.Value.Trim()))`.

```
int intResourceID = 0;

//this will try to convert but you won't see exeptions when failed
Int32.TryParse(hfResourceID.Value, out intResourceID);

//checks if there is a value in the hiddenfield, but throws yellow screen if not convertible
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfResourceID.Value))
{
    intResourceID = Convert.ToInt32(hfResourceID.Value);
}

//catch an error when the value is not convertible, can be wrapped with !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfResourceID.Value)
try
{
    intResourceID = Convert.ToInt32(hfResourceID.Value);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //handle the error, can be seen with ex.Message
}

//if the hidden value is still 0 (for whatever reason) you might not want to execute the query
//so the next part will return and stop executing the rest of the code
if (intResourceID == 0)
{
    return;
}

//update the database, using 'using' will ensure proper closure of the connection and disposing of any objects
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ResourceCreateOrUpdate", connection))
{
    //set the command type and add the parameters
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@ResourceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intResourceID;

    try
    {
        //open the database connection and execute the command
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //there was an error opening the database connection or with the command, can be viewed with ex.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: this at least checks if it's null or not.

Comment: I tried this.  I even put my code within a boolean true, so now I am sure that I have a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Your error regarding the embedded statement is because you a declaring

```
if (strResourceID == "")
        int intResourceID = 0;
    else
        int intResourceID = (Convert.ToInt32(hfResourceID.Value));
```

When decalring a variable directly after an If or else then you need your curly brackets. So...

```
if (strResourceID == "")
{       
    int intResourceID = 0;
}
else
{
    int intResourceID = (Convert.ToInt32(hfResourceID.Value));
}
```

As for your other issues I would need to see your client side code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  There is another If/else statment that doesn't have them and they don't get errors.  I will err on the side of caution and get in the habit of using the curly brackets.

Comment: It's because you're making a declaration of a variable on the very next line after the if ( your 'int'). I also omit curly brackets but only if the statement requires one line of code after the 'if', and it is not a new variable declaration. :)

Comment: It's probably best to read up on what scope is when programming in c#, it will clear things up for you

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on ASP code, specifically the way you are setting hidden field value. I guess it is properly marked as runat=server but maybe some problem is going on in your asp.net code, try to debug client code by using: console.log function and see the output in your console browser.

Comment: I included the asp statement for the hidden field above.

Comment: I tried adding System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline() however I never received anything so I guess that I using it incorrectly.  Is there any way to see the commands in sqlcndCreateOrUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: It looks like the stack trace on the yellow page is what I was just asking about.  Is that correct?  If so, is there a way to see the actual values once within the execution?